# Is it possible to fetch git repository from bower, not just tag or specific commit?

Tags: git, bower

If you try to install via `bower install` or `bower update` package with no tags, or you define `repo#branch` branch, it will fetch just files without `.git` folder, so you can't use it for example for development. Is it possible to force bower to download whole git repository so you can alter the code and then commit and push, checkout another branch and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to use [bower link](http://bower.io/docs/api/#link).

First clone repository with your development package.

```
git clone your-repo-url bower-package-name
cd bower-package-name
bower link
```

Now go to main project and link your package.

```
cd project-name
bower link bower-package-name
```